# lua setting an expiration time using the redis command with 'setex' appears as a permanent key in openresty

Tags: redis, lua, openresty

setting an expiration time using the redis command appears as a permanent key when i do this in openresty with lua script.
the lua script is follow this:

```
local function ip_frequency(ip,red)
    local limit_num=50
    local key = "limit:frequency:"..ip
    local resp, err = red:get(key)
    if resp==nil then   
        local ok,err=red:setex(key,2,1)
        if not ok then
            return false;
        end
    end  

    if type(resp) == "string" then 
        if tonumber(resp) > limit_num then
            return false
        end
    end

    ok, err = red:incr(key)  
    if not ok then
        return false
    end
    return true
end
```

When the openresty program  has run for some time,some permanent keys appear in redis.From this function it can be seen that I did not set a key for the permanent time,but it just happens. Why is that,please help me answer this question. Thank you!
The software version is as follows：

- openresty: 1.17.8.2
- redis: 6.0+
- centos: 8.0+

Answer (score 1):

Openresty connects to redis database and uses it's functionality. Such usage of redis functions in lua or other language is **not atomic**. For redis server it means:  [`redis:get`, pause, `redis:setex`] or [`redis:get`, pause, `redis:incr`]. During pause period can happen a lot of things, event if there is only 1ms, such as cleanup of 'dead' keys.

And this what could happen with your code:

- `local resp, err = red:get(key)`
- You get valid key value which is smaller than `limit_num`
- `ok, err = red:incr(key)`
- Redis checks if key is valid, and removes it if reaches ttl
- Redis checks that there is no such key, so creates key with value=0 and increments key value

So at this point you have permanent key. If you want to avoid permanent keys, use something like: `red:setex(key,2,tonumber(res)+1)` istead of `red:incr(key)`